# Update persistent data in MySQL after using drag and drop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drag-and-drop

The scenario:

I have a simple site with 8 square divs. In two of the divs are pictures and the other six are empty. The pictures are just a placeholder for the labeled divs in order to show who is using what physical machine.

The two pictures are draggable and I have the following javascript to allow them to be dragged and dropped into the empty divs.

The code:

While its not the most elegant, I'm hoping it gets my point across.

```
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        if (ev.target.className === "active") {
            return;
        } else {
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            if (ev.target.id === "A") {
            //switch the value in the database table for "A" from "0" to "1" to persist the location of the picture.
            //switch the value in the database table for "[dragged from]" from "1" to "0" to clear the location of the picture.
            } else if (ev.target.id === "B") {
            //switch the value in the database table for "B" from "0" to "1" to persist the location of the picture.
            //switch the value in the database table for "[dragged from]" from "1" to "0" to clear the location of the picture.
            } else if (ev.target.id === "C") {
            //switch the value in the database table for "C" from "0" to "1" to persist the location of the picture.
            //switch the value in the database table for "[dragged from]" from "1" to "0" to clear the location of the picture.
            } else if (ev.target.id === "D") {
            //switch the value in the database table for "D" from "0" to "1" to persist the location of the picture.
            //switch the value in the database table for "[dragged from]" from "1" to "0" to clear the location of the picture.
            } else if (ev.target.id === "E") {
            //switch the value in the database table for "E" from "0" to "1" to persist the location of the picture.
            //switch the value in the database table for "[dragged from]" from "1" to "0" to clear the location of the picture.
            } else if (ev.target.id === "F") {
            //switch the value in the database table for "F" from "0" to "1" to persist the location of the picture.
            //switch the value in the database table for "[dragged from]" from "1" to "0" to clear the location of the picture.
            }
        }
    }
```

I am unsure how to target the id for the "dragged from" divs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to drag/drop? jQueryUI?

Comment: I'm just using javascript and HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be answering everything, but could get you on the right track hopefully. Using jquery though which I find easier. First set the variable in each of the if/elseifs. In this example I name it "target_variable". Then just fire off an ajax request at the end of the first else statement to a script that connects to and does the updates in the DB.

You should have the dropped ID in the "data" variable I guess?

```
    // fire off the request 
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "db_script.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {target:target_variable,dropped_id:data} 
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){    
        alert("Success!");
    });

    // callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        alert("Fail!");
    });
```

DB script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['target'])) {
$target = $_POST['target'];
$dropped = $_POST['dropped_id'];

//Connect and use the dynamic variables in the DB updates.
}
?>
```